# SiteClosed=true property only visible on STS_Site object within SharePoint Search

Tags: search

I'm searching for a way to create a result source (SharePoint Search) where documents are only returned when the parameter SiteClosed=True. But at this moment the results that come back are STS_Site objects no documents are returned within SharePoint Search Query Tool v2.8.1.

The steps performed so far:

1. Changed the Search Schema
2. Created a new custom Managed Property (Query, Search, Retrieve)
3. Mapped SiteClosed (crawled property) to this new managed property
4. Performed a complete re-index of the whole site collection that is closed
5. Use the Search Query Tool to get the results out of SharePoint Search

**Result:** Only STS_Site objects are returned where the new Managed Property is set to "True"

Comment: How many closed sites do you have? Would it not be easier to limit your result source to results from specific paths?

Comment: Thanks for you're feedback and that's an option, but we have to many closed sites on our production environment. The KQL query doesn't allow more than 2,048 characters. This is also the reason I'm searching for a nice alternative to include more site collections within the result source.

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately, the SiteClosed metadata would likely only apply to the STS_Site objects and not the documents that reside in them. I'm not sure whether result sources allow you to filter documents based on metadata that applies to the site they are from. Hopefully you would not need to create a bespoke search page for this requirement but I'm not sure.

Comment: I hope someone knows a way to create a filter on the way you describe. But for my opinion i'm on a dead route with the nice property siteclosed that only applies on STS_Site object.